# How to send data from one Tab Navigator to another?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an a structure like:

```
    <Tab.Navigator
            
            }}>
                <Tab.Screen name="Train" component={Train} options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
                        <View>
                            <Image
                            source={focused ? require('../assets/images/train_use.png') : require('../assets/images/train.png') }
                            style={{
                                width: 50,
                                height: 50,
                            }}
                            resizeMode='contain'/>
                        </View>
                    ),
                }}/>
                
                <Tab.Screen name="Result" component={Result} options={{
                tabBarButton: () => null,
                tabBarStyle: { display: "none" }}}/>

                <Tab.Screen name="Statistics" component={Statistics} initialParams={{ wordsInText: 0 }} options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
                    ),
                }}/>
                <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} options={{
                tabBarIcon: ({focused})>
                ),
                }}/>
            </Tab.Navigator>
```

**I need to send params from Stack 'Train' into the stack 'Statistics', how can i do it, pls help**

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0); // I need to take this value in Train component

//and take it in the Statistics component
```

I try:

```
routse.params.count
```

But it doesn't work. Pls, help

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass **count** and **setCount** as components params:

```js
import {Button, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {SafeAreaProvider} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {useState} from "react";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function Train({count, setCount}: { count: number, setCount: Function }) {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Train: {count}</Text>
            <Button onPress={() => setCount(count + 1)} title={'up'}/>
        </View>
    );
}

function Result({count, setCount}: { count: number, setCount: Function }) {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Result: {count}</Text>
            <Button onPress={() => setCount(count + 1)} title={'up'}/>
        </View>
    );
}

export default function App() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    return (
        <SafeAreaProvider>
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Tab.Navigator>
                    <Tab.Screen 
                        name="Train" 
                        component={() => <Train count={count} setCount={setCount}></Train>}
                    />
                    <Tab.Screen 
                        name="Result" 
                        component={() => <Result count={count} setCount={setCount}></Result>}
                    />
                </Tab.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're passing an inline function for 'component' prop for the screen 'Train' (e.g. component={() => <SomeComponent />}). Passing an inline function will cause the component state to be lost on re-render and cause perf issues since it's re-created every render. You can pass the function as children to 'Screen' instead to achieve the desired behaviour.